# How to use SFML in gcc windows

Tags: c++

I want to use sfml with the mingw gcc compiler. Whenever I compile my program, I use this command: `g++ main.cpp -lsfml-graphics -L/data/libs/SFML-2.5.1/lib -I/data/libs/SFML-2.5.1/include -o program`. (The data folder is in the directory of main.cpp) But it won’t work, it gives me the error, `SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such directory`

Comment: Make sure that `/data/libs/SFML-2.5.1/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp` exists.

Comment: You want `data/...`, not `/data/...`. (Leading `/` designates an absolute path on *nix, and makes no sense on Windows).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that worked! Thanks. Just got used to using gcc on Ubuntu.

Comment: Make sure you tell your compiler where to find includes (header files). For the GCC compiler, that's the `-I` option.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat To be pedantic; "/" (or "\") *does* make sense on Windows. It means the root directory of the current drive (A:, B:, C:, D: or whatever the current drive is).